# asp.net mvc3 working with master pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, master-pages

In my website, when the user logs in, I want to show the user name and also show a logout button.

In ASP.NET 4.0, we could use the code behind file of the master page to write code for a common thing like this. But I don't know how to achieve this in MVC3. I would not like to pass user name on every page view and add action link of logout on every controller.

Can anyone suggest a better way?

Thanks

Saarthak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a partial. The default template does exactly that. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application using the built-in wizard and look at the `_LogOnPartial.cshtml` partial that's been generated for you and which is invoked in the `_Layout.cshtml` using `@Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")`.

This partial looks like this:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!
    [ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>
}
else {
    @:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]
}
```

It checks if the user is authenticated and if it is it Welcomes him and provides a LogOff link and if he isn't it simply provides a LogOn link.

Same stuff if you are using the WebForms view engine:

`LogOnUserControl.ascx` which is invoked from `Site.Master` using `<% Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); %>`.